# Ionic 2 on function does not refresh the ngModel properly

Tags: android, ios, angular, typescript, ionic2

I use wavesurfer.js and after it's finish playing i want to change the pause button back to play button, but until i open a toggle or do something nothing happen.

```
this.wavesurfer.on('finish', function () {
  this.isPlaying = false;
}.bind(this));
```

I have this simple code, i used *console.log()* so i know it has been called properly, and the binding is also good. However i see the changes only after i do something on the page.

What should i do?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `isPlaying`? A field inside the component?

Comment: That is a simple boolean variable.

Comment: Where is it defined?

Comment: Sorry, i wanted to give you more instructions, but i do not know the commenting yet. :D

So i have a html file where i use _*ngIf=!isPlaying"_ and _*ngIf=isPlaying"_ they are working properly, i declared them at the beginning of my _.ts_ file, and change it in some methods. 

However i can solved it just now, but it is still not the answer, but for me it is ok now.

After i set this variable to false, i call a method, what will jump to the next audio slice, so that method will start a new audio, or open a toggle (with message no more slice) and this refresh the button.

Comment: @Hexiler check my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after it's finish playing i want to change the pause button back to play button, but until i open a toggle or do something nothing happen

I believe you are using `this.playing` in your html..

Your `wavesurfer.js` is changing the value outside Angular's zone.

Try using `ngZone` API:

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private ngZone:NgZone){}

//...
this.wavesurfer.on('finish', function () {
  this.ngZone.run(()=>{
     this.isPlaying = false;
  });
}.bind(this));
```

[NgZone API](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NgZone-class.html)

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome.
(however you forgot a closing bracket after "...false;})" :) )