# Audio play wrong file

Tags: javascript, html, angular, audio, ionic-framework

I can't figure out what's going on with my audio tag.

i've 2 different view on ionic with 2 different controller each one have it's own audio tag.

```
<audio controls="true">
  <source data-ng-src="{{getUrl()}}" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

They work perfecly but when i switch directly between viewAudio1 and viewAudio2 the audio tag won't play the good file even so in dev tools the src don't match the file that the audio tag is playing.
I fire this function to update the audio:

```
function loadAudio() {
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
  document.getElementById('timeline').style.width = '0%';
  audio.setAttribute("src", $scope.getUrl());
  audio.pause();
  audio.load();
}
```

I've try many tings to fix this with no luck.

Comment: Url has been changed properly, so the `getUrl()` method shows new value, when you refresh it? If it has the proper value in the function, but not out of that, you should use [NgZone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43466666/ionic-2-on-function-does-not-refresh-the-ngmodel-properly)

Comment: getUrl give the good value, i can see the expected url in the src attribute of the audio tag. But it doesn't play what's in the src. I've the feeling that the audio tag of the current view is not playing but instead the audio tag form the last view is playing with the old audio ( is that understandable ? ^^ i'm not a native speaker sorry )

Comment: Do you pause the old audio somewhere? Because the `audio.pause()` before `load` want to pause the actual audio, which is a local variable.

So first create a global variable for `audio` then, `pause` (or stop), then set the new attributes and load. 

(btw. i understand you, and same here :D )

Comment: Thx man a `audio.pause()` on `$ionicView.leave` fix the issu =)

Comment: I am happy it is working now, s i add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `audio` variable is local, so create that out of the function as a global variable. Moreover you pause the new audio now. So before loading a new, pause the old one.